# when communicate between component in react or vuejs, what's the different between using callback and event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

As the title say,I am confused about communicate between parent-child components in react or vuejs.

There are two different way to communicate between components.

- First,we can pass a method as a prop to the child component, then the child can communicate with the parent component through the method;
- Second,we can also dispatch an event in the child component and the parent can listen to the event then do something.

My confusion is what is the difference.When should use method and when should use event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [prop](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props) is usually not a method, but a data item representing some piece of program state. Although it is possible ([using `.sync`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types)) for a child to modify a prop and have that change propagate up to the parent , it is most common for the child to simply receive the prop from the parent and reflect updates *from the parent*.

An [event](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) is a way of saying something happened, like a user clicked a button. The component dispatches an event so that the parent (or whatever other component) can make changes to state (which will propagate down via props).

The usual rule is that props go down to children, events go up to parents.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is mainly semantic.

Wehn you listen for an event in the child from the parent like this:

`<child @child-event="callbackMethod">`

What happens internally is basically the same as passing a callback via a prop: `callbackMethod` will be registered internally in the child as a callback to be executed when we `$emit` the event `child-event`.

So the advantage, in my book, is its explicitness:

- When I emit the event in the child, it's immediatly clear to anyone reading my code that I want to communicate something to the outside.
- On the other hand, when I execute a callback in the child template, the reader has to be aware that this function is not an internal `method` of the child but a `prop` from the parent, and is therefore a callback whcih will be executed in the parent's scope.
- The same goes for the parent template: from looking at the template I can immediatly see what is being passed town `:a-prop="data"`, and what callbacks will be executed when the child emits an event: `@some-event=callback"`.
- With a callback in a prop, I have to rely on good naming of the props to  communicate that this is not "data down" but a callback to get something "back up".